# Declare a variable type using a string

Tags: c++, types, declaration, rtti

I have a template which I want to call with the appropriate object type without having to parse a string identifier / enum / typeid.name(), etc.

That is, rather than:

```
switch(varType)
{
case TYPE_ONE:
    templateFunction<TYPE_ONE>();
    break;

case TYPE_TWO:
    templateFunction<TYPE_TWO>();
    break;
...
etc...
}
```

I would prefer to use:

```
templateFunction<GetTypeFromEnum(MyEnum::INT)>();
```

or better yet:

```
templateFunction<GetTypeFromString("int")>();
```

Something like a reversed typeid?

I actually managed to do this in VBA once, so I imagine it must be doable in C++...

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement `boost::variant`?

Comment: boost::variant's visitor implementation would certainly work, but than means calling my templated function from within the approprite operator() overload.  That's ok, I suppose.  It gets a bit more complicated, though, if I have several templated functions that I may wish to call (and I do).  I can see using boost::variant if that's really the only option...  Maybe it's a better option than it seems... ?

Comment: I take that back (a bit).  If I pass a function pointer and an object reference to the visitor before calling it, it does simplify the visitor implementation somewhat...  Nevertheless, I'm a nut about learning C++, so I'm still interested in any alternate methods...  Otherwise, looks like boost::variant may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you redefine your `templateFunction` so to take a dummy parameter?

```
template <typename T>
void templateFunction(const T& Dummy)
{
  // Do nothing with Dummy
}
```

Doing so you just have to pass your variable `varType` where you call the function:

```
templateFunction(varType);
```

Comment: That's just it - I don't actually have a variable of the necessary type.  I want to generate a variable of the type by passing a string which represents it's type name.  Sort of like a reversal of the typeid.name() function - I specify a string and get back a variable of the specified type.

Comment: I understand, your `switch` example confused me. I don't think there's such a thing as a '`typeid().name()` reversal', probably `boost::variant` is your _less bad_ choice.